# I had Teltonika FMA120 Device with c# application , i can't send command from server to device to enable relay?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, stream, gps

I had Teltonika FMA120 Device its working fine with my c# application ,
I got IMEI from device the server acknowledge the device then i got all Position data.

But i can't send any command from server to device.

If i want to enable DOUT 1 and DOUT2 , tO access relay .

I write below in my Stream

```
                            Library.WriteErrorLog("Sending Test Data-----------------------");

                        byte[] ReplyBytesCmd;
                        ReplyBytesCmd = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x0d, 0x8c, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0xb3, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xb4, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01 };
                        //                                  len , id  ,       prms,        1st,           , val , 2nd ,           , val

                        stream.Write(ReplyBytesCmd, 0, 15);
                        Library.WriteErrorLog("Sending Test Data" + ReplyBytesCmd.ToString());
```

Dout1 - Port Id 179
Dout2 - Port Id 180
as per Teltonika Protocol.

Comment: A device is a slave application that is a server.  The client application is the Master that connects to the server.  So a slave will only return data when commanded. You should say : "send any command from client to device (not send any command from server to device).

Comment: How do i change this

Comment: You do not have enough info for me to give an answer.

Comment: What are info you expect ?

Comment: Looks like you need two connections.  One for port 179 and one for port 180.  So just duplicate the code you have and change port number.  You may need to change some variable names so you have unique name for each port.

Answer (score 0):

For Teltonika FMBXXX devices you have to ACK the all the position data that you receive, all of the frames (there may be multiple if it has buffered data).

Then, after you ACK the last position data frame and the device is not sending anything, it is awaiting your commands. This is why it does not close the TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

The type of message you are sending to the FMA120 is unfamiliar to me. You can however use the Codec12 protocol for sending SMS/GPRS command from the server to the device. For example you can wrap the command 'setdigout 11' in a Codec12 message.